# Are there well-specified formal languages that are not regular?

Tags: formal-languages, regular-languages

> Given a finite alphabet, there are well-specified formal
>   languages that can not be recognized by regular expressions, FSAs or regular
>   grammars **True/False**

I am studying for my exam and I am unsure about this question. From my understanding, you generate formal languages from regex, FSA. For i.e. for `a*` our formal language will be

`empty,a,aa,aaa etc.`

So I can identify if a formal language can be described by a regex, but not sure if that is always the case. Could somebody please help me with this?

Comment: Define "well-specified".

Comment: @Raphael You mean "well-specified" isn't well-specified?! :-)

Answer (score 6):

There are indeed well-specified formal languages that cannot be represented by regular expressions, even on a one-letter alphabet. Examples include $\{a^{n^2} \mid n > 0\}$ and $\{a^p \mid p \text{ is a prime number}\}$.

Answer (score 3):

If "well-specified" does not have a very special meaning in your course, than the answer is "yes"; it follows directly from e.g.

$\qquad\displaystyle \mathrm{REG} \subsetneq \mathrm{CFL} \subsetneq 2^{\Sigma^*}$,

a result that was probably presented in the course.

Comment: You are right, but the OP's example was on a one-letter alphabet. And in this case, REG = CFL.

Comment: By yes, do you mean true or false?